# Find a string and extract letter upfront to found string till another specifed string

Tags: regex, string, awk

Find a string and extract letter upfront  to found string till another specifed string

Referring to the below line, I want to find the string 'Task' and print the letters upfront till next immediate (,) comma. in this case '192'

```
60132>, Exclusive Execution, 192 Task(s), Requested Resour
```

I have tried the below given way but it doesn't suits me as sometimes 'Task' string randomly changes its position in the line.

```
| awk -F ',' '{ print $2}' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

Comment: why is this tagged python if you are not using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a simple substitution on a single line, its a job sed was created to do:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*,[[:space:]]*([^,[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*Task.*/\1/' file
192
```

You can do the same in GNU awk with gensub() or any awk with match()+substr() and/or [g]sub()s.

Comment: Thu Feb 19 16:10:07: Submitted from host <iitmlogin5-ib0>, CWD </gpfs3/home/iit muser6/cfs.v2.1.6/HINDCAST/MAY_HINDCAST/hind_20060511_00>, Output File <cfs.stdout.160132>, Error File <cfs.stderr.1 60132>, Exclusive Execution, 192 Task(s), Requested Resour ces <span[ptile=8]>, Requested Network <type=sn_all:protoc ol=mpi:mode=US:usage=shared:instance=1>; RUNLIMIT

Comment: What was your intent in posting that comment? What are you trying to tell us?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `re.search` :

```
>>> s="60132>, Exclusive Execution, 192 Task(s), Requested Resour"
>>> re.search(r'(\d+) (\S+)\(.*\)',s).group(0)
'192 Task(s)'
>>> re.search(r'(\d+) (\S+)\(.*\)',s).group(1)
'192'
>>> re.search(r'(\d+) (\S+)\(.*\)',s).group(2)
'Task'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tvdFxcnOXDBk-kmN)

Comment: I am not using python, could you please help me using awk or sed

Comment: @user3742796 and im not expert in  `awk`. but glad that you find the answer !:)